# Is : $||(a+b)^2 || \le ||a||^2+2||ab||+||b||^2$ true in any form when a,b, are elements of a space?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $E$ be a space and $a,b$ be elements of it,

$$||(a+b)^2 || \le ||a||^2+2||ab||+||b||^2 $$, where $|| \cdot ||$ is most of the time a sum norm ,  then also a  form for integrals shows up some times :

$$\int |a(t)+b(t)|^2dt \le \int |a(t)|^2dt +2 \int |a(t)b(t)|dt +\int |b(t)|^2dt $$

How to prove that this is true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ in any ring.

$|x+y+z| \leq |x| + |y| + |z|$ for any norm.

Just put the two together.